# Getting ASP MVC exception Exception type: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Exception message: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

```
~/Views/deployment/Error.aspx
~/Views/deployment/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Views/deployment/Error.cshtml
~/Views/deployment/Error.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
```

Below is the call stack:

> at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
> context)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState           innerState)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult,     ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.
> IExecutionStep.Execute()    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
> completedSynchronously)

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Comment: You wrote an action named Error in controller X and it cannot find its view named Error.cshtml on folder  X You can fix by adding file to that folder

Comment: Could this be a permissions issue? I see some message from the event log as below:                                                                                                                             User:
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type:
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Thread information:
Thread ID: 58
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
Is impersonating: False

Comment: If you already have Error.cshtml in your folder-"deployment" then yes maybe a permission issue try changing application pool identity in IIS

Comment: try to check the your site application pool identity and assign the iis_iusrs, iusr or  IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool permission to the site folder . make sure theurl is  correct.